# Getting rownames for row indices in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames as follows:

```
####DATA A

AGT1 0.5 0.6
AGT2 0.4 0.3
AGT3 0.1 0.7
AGT4 0.2 0.1

#### DATA B

      row row2

 GCT1  1     2
 GCT2  2     2
 GCT3  3     1
 GCT4  4     2
 GCT5  5     4
 GCT6  6     4
```

I would like to get the names of the row indices in row2 by indexing to DATA A and did this

```
C=DATA A[DATA B$row2,]
```

But this gives me something like

```
AGT2
AGT2.1
AGT1
AGT2.2
AGT4
```

Is there any other better way of doing it for indexing non-unique row values avoiding .1, .2 ?

So the expected output looks something like this:

DATA B

```
      row row2

 GCT1  1     AGT2
 GCT2  2     AGT2
 GCT3  3     AGT1
 GCT4  4     AGT2
 GCT5  5     AGT4
 GCT6  6     AGT4
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Edited post for expected output. So those row indices in row2 of DATA B should get the rownames from DATA A.

Comment: Something like `B$row2 = rownames(A)[ B$row1 ]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like this

C<-DATA A[DATA B$row2,]

output looks like

```
AGT2   0.5 0.6
AGT2.1 0.5 0.6
AGT1   0.5 0.6
AGT2.2 0.5 0.6
AGT4   0.2 0.1
```

and then

```
DATA B$row2<-sapply(strsplit(rownames(C),"\\."), function(x) paste0(head(x,-1),collapse=".") )
```

Final output is what we want

```
        row    row2

   GCT1  1     AGT2
   GCT2  2     AGT2
   GCT3  3     AGT1
   GCT4  4     AGT2
   GCT5  5     AGT4
   GCT6  6     AGT4
```